# How do I move Active Directory user information to the Exchange Global Address Book?

Tags: active-directory, exchange, outlook

I am running Exchange 2013 and I have noticed in Outlook that a lot of the contacts in the Global Address Book are out of date. 
I recently went and update all of the Active Directory details so how can I get the GAL to populate based on the updated AD?

Also, I want to remove the contacts from GAL which are disabled in AD.

Thanks.

Comment: Some links that might help you. If any of this worked for you, please comment below, so that I can post that answer here, in addition to these links. 1. [USER APPEARS IN “ALL USERS” LIST BUT NOT IN GLOBAL ADDRESS LIST (GAL)](http://teknologist.net/2012/user-appears-in-all-users-list-but-not-in-global-address-list-gal/) 2. [User not showing up in Global Address List](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/359190-user-not-showing-up-in-global-address-list?page=1#entry-2361159) 3. [Exchange - New User(s) Not Showing Up On Global Address List](http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000775.htm)

Answer (score 0):

There is a cmdlet you can use to accomplish this.

To update your GAL
Update-GlobalAddressList -Identity "Default Global Address List" -DomainController "YourDomainControllerName"

To hide disabled users in your GAL
get-mailbox "Disabled_User" | set-mailbox -HiddenFromAddress
ListsEnabled $true
 Or this will do this operation for all disabled mailboxes:

Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited |Where{($_.UserAccountControl -like “AccountDisabled*”)} | set-mailbox -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $true

Comment: Was the answer of any assistance to you?